# Why would the "modified" date not change when a file is modified?

Tags: linux

I have a file with a modified date sometime in January 2012. This is wrong, because I know for a fact the content has been modified since then.

I'm pretty sure the file was modified through a PHP script some time in October 2015.

Why would the "modified" date not change when the file is modified? Is it related to some kernel setting or is it related to PHP?

Edit:
The disk is mounted in `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
/dev/mapper/something /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

When I run `mount` I can see that there are some stuff mounted on `/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`, `/run` and `/boot`, but the file is saved in `/var/www/mysite/myfile.php` so it should be the line in fstab that's relevant.

Comment: Can you post the output of the `mount` command along with the location that the file is saved?

Comment: @DavidKing See my edit.

Comment: If you try `touch /var/www/mysite/myfile.php` does it update the timestamps?  If it does then PHP is editing the file in a way that doesn't affect the timestamps.  If it doesn't then there's something wrong with your kernel or filesystem that isn't allowing the modifications.

Comment: I wouldn't use "touch", since that modifies the file unnecessarily. First I'd check the `ctime` of the file to see if some process had perhaps written to the file and restore its `mtime`.  You can see `ctime` using `ls -lc`.